# Find a specific string in html source

Tags: html, c++, string

My goal is to find a predefined string in an HTML source of a specific site that I have extracted using c++, but I'm getting some errors. Here is my source code so far:

So after I connect to the internet and the site and all I have this...

```
addr = InternetOpenUrl...  
dmbp = char dmbp[5000]
dba = DWORD dba = 0

while (InternetReadFile(addr, dmbp, 80000, &dba) && dba)
{
    string str2 = dmbp;
    size_t sf1 = str2.find(string1);
    if (sf1!=string::npos)
    {printf("found");
           // manipulate it...
    }else{printf("not found");}
}
```

My problem is that it never actually confirms that it found the value that I need, it always says that the value is not found, but I even statically insert the page and look at myself and i can see the value that i need, it just doesnt show up. Does anyone with experience in html extraction with c++ know what I'm missing or how I can get this to work?

Comment: Did you try printing string1 and str2 just before the call to find?

Comment: If you try to read 80k into a 5k buffer you're likely to have trouble.  You might want to post a short complete example of your real code.  You might also consider what would happen if the item you are searching for is split between two calls to `InternetReadFile` since you're not accumulating all of the data, you're just discarding it.

Comment: The 5k and 80k was just a mistake, i just supressed the code since I didn't want to reveal the product I am making for my employer so I guess I missed that part. What do you mean by "the item you are searching for is split between two calls"?

Comment: Imagine your buffer is 5k and the value you're searching for is a 10 character string located at (5k - 5) in the html.  You'll never find it, because the whole value is never seen in a single read call, only the first 5 or last 5 characters.  Reducing your code to a small self-contained example might lead to you solving the problem on your own, or at least isolating whether the code you've shown is even the problem.

Comment: Read your buffer, scan it, if not found, discard all but len-1 of the content, where `len` is the length of the prospect string. Move those bytes to the *beginning* of your buffer, then continue reading up to buffersize-len-1 bytes, storing starting at buffer[len-1], and repeat. its a little more tedious than that in real implementation, but the general idea should be clear.

Comment: That does not look like C++ to me. Perhaps you should post the real code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the string search code as far as I can see, the problem is that we don't know exactly what you are searching for.

As pure HTML can be full of special characters (such as `&#34;` or `&quot;`, the string you might be looking for should deal with those characters. Also, strings can contain newlines and html tags (such as `<b></b>` within a single word), and they should be specified in the search string as `string::find` looks for an exact match (including any newline).

Also, I suggest debugging your code and see if the website's text/code is actually loaded into `str2`.

Looking at the information given that's currently the only issue I can think of why your code doesn't work.